# Why python multi-threading and Queue does not help accelerate reading a big number of files?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I am writing a Python program to read about 110000+ text files from local file system and push  them into MongoDB. Here is my code snippet.

class EmailProducer (threading.Thread):

```
def __init__(self, threadID, queue, path):
    self.threadID = threadID
    self.queue = queue
    self.path = path
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

def run(self):
    if (queue.empty()):
        files = os.listdir(self.path)
        print(len(files))
        for file in files:
            queue.put(file)
```

class EmailConsumer (threading.Thread):

```
def __init__(self, threadID, queue, path, mongoConn):
    self.threadID = threadID
    self.queue = queue
    self.mongoConn = mongoConn
    self.path = path
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
def run(self):
    while (True):
        if (queue.empty()):
            mongoConn.close()
            break
        file = queue.get()
        self.mongoConn.persist(self.path, file)
```

The EmailProducer instance reads files from local filesystem and store them in the queue if the queue is empty; and the EmailConsumer instance fetch files from the queue and push them into Mongo.  I also wrote a sequential version of the same functionality. 
I run both on my ubuntu 12.04 32 bit desktop with an i-5 quad-core processor and timed both of them.  The multithreaded version started with 1 producer and 7 consumer. However, both of them cost approximately 23.7 sec real time and 21.7 sec user time. I thought threading would help here, but numbers told me it does not help.

Any one has any insightful thoughts on the reason ?

Comment: Maybe the limit is from your hard drive. Reading a large number of small file is very taxing on hard drive.

Answer (score 3):

Threading is not very useful for IO bound operations. Especially not with a Global Interpreter Lock. So there was only ever one thread running at a time. I'm surprised it wasn't faster without threads. Look at reading the files asynchronously using the [select module](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html) or a third party library.

Comment: single threaded one outperforms the threading version by a very small margin when it does in my tests.

Answer (score 0):

Python threading is somewhat limited by the [Global Interpreter Lock](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) in CPython, which [is considered to be pretty poor in terms of performance](https://blip.tv/carlfk/mindblowing-python-gil-2243379), and probably contributes to your results.

All C level extensions also require [specific GIL support to avoid "defeating threads"](http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html#threads) by holding the GIL while blocking on an external resource.  That means that if you are using a C layer library to, eg, talk to MongoDB it may block other threads while operating.  (I have no idea if it does - just that it may.)